# Placing VBA Code input into Excel WB directly

Tags: vba, excel, input, excel-2013

I've written my code but I have to use it on multiple workbooks (one per day), to transfer data into a collective excel database. I need to specify the workbook in the code. I won't be using the code but rather people with no experience so I want to minimize the complexity. Is there a way I can make a cell or button in the collective workbook to specify which workbook to use for the code? So that anyone using it would only need to type the name of the file and open the input workbook?  Similar to a command button but with variable input.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? My suggestion would be a userform with a button to open the desired workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it easiest to use forms that other users are familiar with.  VBA lets you call standard Windows dialogue boxes, such as the `Open File` dialogue.  The dialogue returns a string that is the path to the workbook.  You can then create a workbook object from that path and carry out usual operations on it.

In the code below, I've assumed you've placed a button on a worksheet (called `OpenWorkbookButton`) and placed the code to call the dialogue, get the file path and create the workbook object within the OpenWorkbookButton_Click() event handler.  This the passes the workbook as an argument to the subroutine that carries out your usual operations and this way the user doesn't have to see the workbook be open or interact in any way.

```
Private Sub OpenWorkbookButton_Click()

    Dim wbPath As String
    wbPath = Application.GetOpenFilename _
                        (Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
                        FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(wbPath)

    Call DoMyUsualOperations(wb)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim File1 As String 'Filename for open and save
Dim i As Integer
Dim SplitArray() As String 'Used to split filename

'Open File
        File1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="Excel, *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm", Title:="Select a File")
        If File1 <> "False" Then
            'Remove path
            SplitArray() = Split(File1, "\")
            i = UBound(SplitArray)
            File1 = SplitArray(i)
            On Error Resume Next
            If Workbooks(File1) Is Nothing Then
                'File not open
                Workbooks.Open File1
            Else
                'File already open
            End If
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'Activate and show windows
        On Error Resume Next
        Workbooks(File1).Worksheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Public variable inside the procedure? :)

Comment: Quick cut and paste from a bigger userform. I use i as a general purpose counter. But yes not needed. Making the file name public is useful though.

Comment: You didn't get my point... You can't have `Public` variables inside a procedure. Use `Dim` instead. :)

Comment: In the userform I pulled this from, they aren't inside the procedure. But yes thank you for the clarification. :)

Comment: So are you not going to fix your post?

Comment: How do I fix my post?

Comment: You can edit your post and replace `Public` with `Dim`?

Comment: Oh I didn't know I could do that.